# Google scripts function comparing two ranges working in console but not in sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Diffing two user ranges in Google Sheets, this works in console but doesn't work in the sheet. Can someone please explain why?

```
function DIFF(a, b) {
  return a.filter(function(v){
     return b.indexOf(v) === -1 ? true : false;
  }).length
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a range to a custom Sheets function, it gets either

- a single value, if the range consists of one cell, or
- a double array otherwise. Even if the range is one dimensional: for example, you get `[[1], [2], [3]]` for a column range or `[[1, 2, 3]]` for a row range.

Your `DIFF` function assumes that the arguments are ordinary arrays of values. So you need to flatten double arrays, or turn a single value to an array. This is what the function `flatten` does.

```
function flatten(arg) {
  if (arg.constructor === Array) {
    return arg.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.concat(b);
    });
  }
  else {
    return [arg];
  }
}
```

Then `DIFF` can be like this:

```
function DIFF(a, b) {
  a = flatten(a);
  b = flatten(b);
  return a.filter(function(v) {
     return b.indexOf(v) === -1;
  }).length
}
```

(Aside: ternary operator `: ? true : false` was redundant here, so I removed it.)